# Pass command line arguments to Docker with Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

I have a Java socket application that requires a port number as a CLI argument. On my local machine I can run it via:

```
docker run -d -p 1111:1111 --name <name> --link <link> <foo>/<bar> 1111
```

The problem is that I haven't found a solution to pass the port number when using Ansible (I have a different task that pulls the image). Current task:

```
- name: Run server
      docker:
          name: <name>
          image: <foo>/<bar>
          state: reloaded
          ports:
              - "1111:1111"
          links:
              - "<link>"
```

Is there a way to pass the port as a CLI argument? Or is there a simple way to work around this? I've though about uploading a new image or using [the command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) but neither seem like right way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no native support to pass arbitrary arguments in Ansible's [Docker](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) module. See [passing extra args to docker: task](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/DXCg-2drIIE).

Can't you use [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) module to achieve what you want?

Comment: Since there's no support I went with the command module since I don't need to run the command through a shell. I'll accept this as an answer since command is basically shell, just no shell support :)

Answer (score 6):

If you can change the image I would recommend to use [environment vars](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) instead . That's supported by the docker module.

```
- name: Run server
  docker:
    name: <name>
    image: <foo>/<bar>
    state: reloaded
    ports:
      - "1111:1111"
    links:
      - "<link>"
    env:
      MY_PORT: 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass argument using `command` parameter:

```
docker_container:
    name: myredis
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

Or you may rewrite existing entrypoint using `entrypoint` parameter

```
docker_container:
    name: myjavascript
    image: theirjavascript
    entrypoint: ["node", "--max_old_space_size=4096", "dist/index.js", "start"]
```